# assigining new key value pair to stdclass object in foreach php

Tags: php, object, pdo, foreach

Im fetching a pdo object with data from the database. now when i foreach this data I want to add extra key values but this doest work.

```
            foreach ($deliveryCompanies as $k=>$v) {
            $k->test = 'test';
        }
```

this returns
    Type: ErrorException
     Code: 2
     Message: Attempt to assign property of non-object

the object looks like this

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [delivery_id] => 2
            [delivery_location_id] => 34
            [delivery_category_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [delivery_id] => 4
            [delivery_location_id] => 34
            [delivery_category_id] => 1
        )

)
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because $k is the key, not the value. You need to do $v->test ='test';